# Static initialization of a derived class

Tags: c#, static-methods

The output of the following program is

```
base init
BaseMethod
derived init
DerivedMethod
```

Eg, the call to the base method from the derived class triggers the Base class's init stub and not the same of the Derived class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Derived.BaseMethod());
        Console.WriteLine(Derived.DerivedMethod());
    }
}

class Base
{
    public static string BaseMethod() { return "BaseMethod"; }
    static bool init = InitClass();
    static bool InitClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base init");
        return true;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public static string DerivedMethod() { return "DerivedMethod"; }
    static bool init = InitClass();
    static bool InitClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("derived init");
        return true;
    }
}
```

In reality, my base class has no initialization needs, but my derived class does, and I'd like to ensure that it's run before anyone interacts with the class in any way. Unfortunately, most of the interaction with it is via methods defined in the base class as per the example above.

I can alter the Derived class to hide the BaseMethod as follows:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public static new string BaseMethod() { return Base.BaseMethod(); }
    public static string DerivedMethod() { return "DerivedMethod"; }
    static bool init = InitClass();
    static new bool InitClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("derived init");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this produces the desired result of initializing the derived class on the call to Derived.BaseMethod(), but it isn't very satisfying since it's meaningless 'routing' code that would have to do be done for every public static base method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If all of your operations are static you probably shouldn't be using inheritance to begin with, because, as you can see, it's not really giving you pretty much anything.  Static members are statically bound, as you're seeing.

Comment: Those are fair points, but not all of the classes' methods are static. The static methods mostly include things like a 'list' method, which returns the names of all the configured objects, or a 'load' method, which returns an instance of an existing configured object. The particular problem here is that one of my derived classes requires that a 'Default' configured object exist, and I'd like to lazily check for and instantiate it when the class is accessed.

Comment: If you would have had static methods in the base class, you'd not have faced this dilemma since then a constructor in the derived class would be run if you had one. Now since the class might not be initialized when you call it's methods the easiest is to do what you suggested yourself I believe. However, if you have time on your hands, you can look into Attributes. Create an attribute that takes a method, in the attribute run the constructor and then run the method it received. Also, like pointed out by others, you could simply choose to wrap the class instead of deriving it.

Comment: So why are you opposed to it being lazily created?  You say that that's what you want, and that's exactly what you're getting.  It's not eagerly computing a value that it knows isn't needed (yet).  That's the whole idea of lazy initialization.

Comment: List() is a base method, but I'd like Derived.List() to initialize the default derived object. Currently this isn't happening because Derived.List() only initializes the base class.

Answer (score 2):

instead of the derived class using `static new bool InitClass()`, why not use a standard static constructor?

```
  static bool init = false;

  static Derived()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("derived init");
        init = true;
    }
```

See [C# Static Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

Comment: The static constructor seems to be running under the same conditions as the above init method. In particular, it doesn't run when Derived.BaseMethod() is called :(